# Cache clearing without drush

Tags: 8, caching

I am using Drupal 8, and I am wondering how I can clear more caches than the button in admin/config/development/performance does.

I have had trouble with installing Drush, so I am looking for any alternative solutions.

Answer (score 8):

Just execute [core/rebuild.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!rebuild.php/8).
As the documentation says, it rebuilds the cache even when Drupal doesn't work; it require a token you can generate with [scripts/rebuild_token_calculator.sh](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!scripts!rebuild_token_calculator.sh/8), so you call it as http://example.com/core/rebuild.php?token=TOKEN_YOU_GET_FROM_THE_SCRIPT.

Comment: You can avoid the token by temporarily using `$settings['rebuild_access'] = TRUE;` in your settings.php, too.  Just remember to remove it when you are done as it not safe to leave this unprotected on a live site.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Admin Toolbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar) for Drupal 8, it emulates all the dev functions from a drop down menu like we had in Drupal 7 from Admin Menu. Be sure to activate "Admin Toolbar Extra Tools" as part of the module.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That button clears all caches, just like drush would.

The only alternative to that would be to clear the caches directly in the database, which isn't much convenient.

Comment: The callback attached to that button does a lot more than just clear caches tables in the database.  The biggest differences are probably the container invalidation and the router rebuild that get triggered.

Comment: Oh, and to be extra clear, that button and drush do the exact same thing and eventually call [`drupal_flush_all_caches()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/8).  It is just that there is more to it than simply truncating the `{cache*}` tables from the database.

Answer (score 0):

The methods I've come across for clearing the JavaScript cache in Drupal (either from the Admin UI or from Drush) do not work reliably, which causes a **huge** amount of frustration when you're using a framework on top of Drupal to create a web application.

The workaround I use is to alter the version number in your module.libraries.yml file, which is at the root of your module folder.

Example:

```
reporting:
  version: 1.31
  css:
    layout:
      css/jquery.notifyBar.css: {}
      css/tagify.min.css: {}
      css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css: {}
    theme:
      css/reporting-theme.css: {}
  js:
    js/smsw-utils.js: {}
    js/shim.min.js: {}
    js/xlsx.full.min.js: {}
    js/reporting.js: {}
    js/knockout-min.js: {}
    js/jquery.notifyBar.js: {}
    js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js: {}
    js/tagify.min.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```